# Glue Pyspark Job has long runtimes to write data to s3 with partitionBy

Tags: dataframe, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue, parquet

I am trying to write data to S3 bucket using the Glue Pyspark job where I am using the below code to write data from pyspark dataframe to s3 after partitioning.

```
result_df.write.partitionBy("marketplace_id", "id").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").parquet(s3_output_path)
```

I know partitioning by "id" which is of very high cardinality (millions of records) is not advisable. But if I had to do it, what is the efficient way of doing it?

My Glue Configurations are as follows:

Worker type: G.8X
Number of workers: 20
Max capacity: 160 DPUs
Glue version: Glue 3.0

I tried repartition as shown below. But it did not help:

```
result_df.repartition(15).write.partitionBy("marketplace_id", "id").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").parquet(s3_output_path)
```

Kindly advice.

I tried repartition and it did not help.